# Creating a route for static assets or images in Hasekll Spock

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, haskell-warp, haskell-spock

I have this basic Spock application taken from its website:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    do ref <- newIORef 0
       spockCfg <- defaultSpockCfg EmptySession PCNoDatabase (DummyAppState ref)
       runSpock 8080 (spock spockCfg app)

app :: SpockM () MySession MyAppState ()
app =
    do get root $
           text "Hello World!"
       get -- ??? route for "/img/"???
```

I have an html page which I can return like this:

However, an html page contains a some "img" tags. How do I need to create a route so that the images resolves? Say, the images are location in the folder "img".

Answer (score 1):

Something I like to do is to use the `wai-middleware-static` middleware to serve a static directory :

```
app :: SpockM () MySession MyAppState ()
app = do
    middleware $ staticPolicy (addBase "static")
    ...
```